# how to sort numbers that are longer than integer.max in java

Tags: java, sorting

I am wondering how to sort numbers that are longer than integer.max?

Does anyone could help me ?

for example, userid 12345678901 vs 12345678900?

Comment: Did you tried this,post that code

Comment: use `long` and if long is not enough then use `BigInteger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the type `Long` or `BigInteger`.

But the Long type may resolve your problem becouse your max value is larger.

```
Long.MAX_VALUE is 2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807
```

For order you can use an ArrayList and call the method sort in Collections like this:

```
List<Long> values = new ArrayList<>();
//put all values in your list.
Collections.sort(values);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `long` type, and sort an array of `long` values.